# How to get store object from existing store object in ExtJs

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I am using ExjJs 4.2 .I have two grids displaying different data. In one javascript file i have to include both the grids. I am loading the store for the first grid like

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                model: 'Writer.Person',
                autoLoad: true,
                proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',            
                    url : 'findPatientRecordAction',
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        successProperty: 'success',
                        root: 'data',
                        messageProperty: 'message'
                    },
                    writer: {
                        type: 'json',
                        encode: true,
                        root: 'data'
                    },
                    fields: ['id','notes', 'startDate', 'endDate'],
                },
            });
```

The JSON object store looks like this :

> "data":[{"id":35,"notes":"hiii","startDate":"2013-04-30","endDate":"2013-05-02"}]} , "details":[{"id":14,"document":"docpath12345","date":"2013-04-28"}]

Actually the first grid will display only the 'data' part of JSON and the second grid will display the 'details' part of JSON. So ideally i should not load the store object again for the second grid(what i am doing now).I want to declare one more store type variable and reuse value of 'store' (the 'documents' part of store) to become the store for second grid as

I am loading the second store as of now like this

> var store2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {

```
                model: 'Writer.Document',
                autoLoad: true,
                proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',            
                    url : 'findPatientRecordAction',
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        successProperty: 'success',
                        root: 'details',
                        messageProperty: 'message'
                    },
                    writer: {
                        type: 'json',
                        encode: true,
                        root: 'details'
                    },
                    fields: ['id','document', 'date'],
                },
            });`.
```

In both the cases i am calling the same action and getting the same JSON.

Can anyone help me out here that how can I declare another store object and get the value from the existing 'store' so that i should not have to load the same data for 2 times.

Regards : Dev

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the first store have autoload set to false.  Then in the second store use the load event to inject the records into the first using that stores active proxy data:

```
var store2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Writer.Document',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',            
        url : 'findPatientRecordAction',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            successProperty: 'success',
            root: 'details',
            messageProperty: 'message'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            encode: true,
            root: 'details'
        },
        fields: ['id','document', 'date'],
    },
    listeners: {
        load: function(store, records, successful, eOpts){
            if(successful)
            {
                store1.loadData(store.proxy.reader.rawData.data);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: 2fast4me ;) anyway, this is the answer +1

Answer (score -1):

I'll replace:

```
listeners: {
    load: function(store, records, successful, eOpts){
        if(successful)
        {
            store1.loadData(**store.getRange()**);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the same, I think:

store.proxy.reader.rawData.data <--> store.getRange()

Comment: Not the same... this would have both stores have the same dataset.

Comment: yeah, sorry, I didn't read that he only want a little part of data.. It's my fault-